# DOS debug like program for 32-bit x86 assembly

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, x86-16, dos

Many of you may recall the old DOS program--debug.  Though outdated in many respects, one of the nice things about it was that one could easily find the byte-sequence for a given instruction without having to go through the steps of writing a program, compiling, disassembling, examining the file contents, ....  Enter the instruction, then dump the instruction address.  'debug' regrettably does not do 32 bit instructions.

Does anyone know of a tool that does something similar for 32-bit x86 instructions?  I don't want to go through the whole compile process; I just need to be able to enter a couple of instructions and have it spew out the length of the instruction and its byte sequence.

Comment: Interesting question!. Why not tagging "debugging"?

Comment: Hadn't thought to add the 'debugging' tag until you mentioned it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOS `debug` was an interactive assembler as well as a debugger, entering assembly code resulted in that line being converted immediately to machine code - which is what you dumped out.

So all you need is to automate your favourite assembler with a script or batch-file.

Here's a bash function I came up with in a minute or two using the popular [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) assembler:

```
opcode() {
  echo $* > tmp.S && nasm tmp.S -o tmp.o && od -x tmp.o
  rm -f tmp.o tmp.S
}
```

Takes less than a second.  Invocation looks like this:

```
$ opcode mov eax, [ebx]
0000000 6667 038b
0000004
$ opcode fadd st0,st1
0000000 c1d8
0000002
```

Not brilliant, but you can tweak od command-line for better output.  This idea should work with any command-line assembler as long as you tell it to use a simple binary output format.

Answer (score 2):

FreeDOS Debug/X is a line-oriented debugger originally developed as a clone for MS-DOS Debug. However, it has gained support for 32-bit instructions. Both its assembler and disassembler fully support at least 486-level instructions. Access to and display of the 386+ registers is also included. This debugger, for one, supports 32-bit code (using `a32` or `o32` prefixes) in Real/Virtual 86 Mode. For another, the DebugX variant allows running the debugger as a DPMI client to load and debug another DPMI client. The client to debug can run in 16-bit or 32-bit Protected Mode. This is true of all of the following members of the FreeDOS Debug family.

The original Debug/X is still being developed from time to time. It can be found on github: https://github.com/Baron-von-Riedesel/DOS-debug/releases

There is also the fork Enhanced Debug, which is nonfree. It's available at https://pcdosretro.github.io/enhdebug.htm

Finally, I forked Debug/X starting in 2008. Based on this codebase I created lDebug, which is still line-oriented but is more advanced than either of the others. Manual and releases are linked on my website: https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug

Comment: The accepted answer is a bash script using Unix shell commands.  Probably this answer is useful for some people, but I'm not sure the [dos] tag belongs on the question.  I think the OP was looking for tools on a modern OS (which they forgot to specify!) which can do some of the things they did with `debug` on DOS. You're answering the question of a 32-bit-capable / 386-aware version of `debug` for actual DOS, which is probably fine: people looking for that could easily end up here from Google based on the question title. I guess the DOS tag isn't hurting anything; I marked my answer as [linux]

Comment: @PeterCordes "people looking for that could easily end up here from Google based on the question title" -- Yes, I did actually find this question from a web search so it's certainly possible to come here from a search for "debug dos".

Answer (score 2):

On [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), I use a shell script I call `asm-link`, which has a `-d` option to assemble + link and then disassemble with `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.  It's part of [my answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649).

The script could be ported to Windows using `nasm -f win64` or OS X using `-f macho64`, perhaps even to DOS if you wanted that.

NASM defaults to the `.text` section at the top of the file, and GNU Binutils `ld` defaults to putting the ELF entry point at the start of the `.text` section if it can't find a `_start` symbol, so even linking works with absolutely minimal `.asm` source files, and you can even run them in GDB and single-step.  `cat > foo.asm` ... type some and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> is one way to create a file, or of course your favourite light-weight editor.

Example use:

```
$ cat > foo.asm
mov eax, ecx
lea rdi, [rel $]
$ asm-link -dn foo.asm
+ nasm -felf64 -Worphan-labels foo.asm
+ ld -o foo foo.o
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000

foo:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <__bss_start-0x1000>:
  401000:       89 c8                   mov    eax,ecx
  401002:       48 8d 3d f9 ff ff ff    lea    rdi,[rip+0xfffffffffffffff9]        # 401002 <__bss_start-0xffe>
```

What I actually type on the second command line is `asm<tab> -dn <alt-.>`.
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> recalls the last token from previous commands so I don't have to retype the filename.  And tab-completion for the command works since my system doesn't have any other commands that start with `asm`.

`nasm -felf64` (passed by the script, or `-f elf32` if you use `asm-link -m32`) implies `BITS 64` (or `BITS 32`) for assembling.

GNU Binutils `objdump`'s output format is fairly nice for showing the machine code, with addresses that make it easy to see length, and spaces that make it easy to see byte boundaries.  (Unlike `nasm -l /dev/stdout -f elf64  foo.asm` listings which cram hex digits together.)

The `+ nasm ...` and `+ ld` output lines are from bash `set -x`.  The `-n` option to the script uses NASM instead of YASM; back when I originally wrote it, I usually used YASM.  I should probably update the default to be NASM.

Comment: I didn't get `asm<tab> -dn <alt+.>`. alt-`.` recalls ... Does pressing the TAB key make the text "-link" appear? I suppose <alt+.> in essence is the same as alt-. but I think it could be a tad confusing, the + vs the -.

Comment: @SepRoland: yes, via tab-completion, since my system doesn't have any other command that start with `asm` in my `$PATH`.  Good point about `<alt+.>` vs. `alt-.` in other places.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few simple, 32-bit command line debuggers to be found. Based on your description, [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) might fit your needs well. At least some versions of Microsoft's [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) include one named CDB, which stands for Commandline DeBugger (though I haven't verified that the linked version includes it...)

Comment: Interesting.  Not yet sure if it suits my purposes, but I am still playing around with it.  Thank you for the suggestion.