# easy way to get opcodes

Tags: assembly, x86

I know how to get the opcodes and the corresponding assembly syntax from an executable; however is there an easy way to get the opcodes of a particular assembly instruction alone, without writing a program using the same and then, manually linking and loading it and doing an objdump on the executable?

Is there a simple way to find the corresponding opcodes of a particular instruction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use gdb's (GNU Debugger's) x/bx command.

I made a tutorial here:

<del>http://aimbots.net/tutorials/9276-how-get-op-codes.html</del>

http://aimbots.net/threads/9276-How-to-get-OP-codes

Answer (score 4):

For x86, you can just look them up in the Intel Manual ([Part 1 (A-M)](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253666.pdf), [Part 2 (N-Z)](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253667.pdf)). And no, I don't know why the manual is split in 2 parts.

Comment: You can download the whole vol.2 of the SDM as a single PDF instead of split; computers have enough RAM these days to comforatably work with larger PDFs.  (There's even the whole SDM as a single PDF, which is often too huge to search efficiently.)  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html has links for combined, 4-part, and 10-part (total across all volumes).

Answer (score 4):

I asked a similar question a while back ([DOS debug like program for 32-bit x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206535/dos-debug-like-program-for-32-bit-x86-assembly)).

Someone was kind enough to provide me with an automated script to do this.  You can follow the link to question, or refer to the script they provided to me below ...

```
opcode() {
  echo $* > tmp.S && nasm tmp.S -o tmp.o && od -x tmp.o
  rm -f tmp.o tmp.S
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not give the correct result.  Or rather, the correct result is buried in the hexdump.  For example, the correct opcode for 'jmp eax' is 'FF E0' whereas the above function gives 'FF 66 00 E0'.

Comment: @sillyMunky: The 0x66 seen in your hexdump indicates that the operand size is being overridden.  If you want it done for 32-bit, you will need to add the appropriate flag/switch to the commands.

Comment: @sillyMunky: Assembled in 16-bit mode (like this is doing with the default `-fbin` and without a `bits 32` directive), `jmp eax` is `66 FF E0`.  You can see that from `nasm -l /dev/stdout` to get a listing, too.  `FF 66 00 E0` would be a very different instruction, with `66` as the modrm byte for an `FF` opcode, with no prefix.  The default output from `od -x` is in chunks of 2-byte as a 16-bit integer, which isn't very useful for variable-length x86 machine code.  Use `hexdump -C` or something, or just use NASM's own listing output.  `nasm -felf32 -l/dev/stdout foo.asm`

Answer (score 3):

[X86 Opcode and Instruction Reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/) contains a bunch of reference tables of instructions and their corresponding opcodes on both 32-bit and 64-bit x86 processors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want opcodes.  But if its for exploit development you probably already have metasploit which comes with a really useful ruby script called nasm_shell.rb (in the tools directory).

Each  line you type comes out as an ascii hex representation of the correct opcodes.

If its for some other purpose or you don't want some heavyweight toolkit like metasploit hanging around for whatever reason, you can just pull out the script and install its dependencies.  It uses Rex and assumes nasm is installed.

If you want to adapt it the actual code you need is just a few lines in the function shell.run